# 2 errors detected in the compilation of "/temp/tempft_00003f44_000000000-9 network kernels.compute_61.cpp1.ii

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, yolo

While running 'make' command, It ends up with exit code 1, having 2 errors detected in the compilation of "/temp/tempft_00003f44_000000000-9 network kernels.compute_61.cpp1.ii

[image]

Comment: I resolved this issue by upgrading my jetpack 4.2 to 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by upgrading my jetpack 4.2 to 4.5.